# Blender render FLIP Particles from fluid simulation

Tags: 3d, blender, particle-system, shading

I want to shade and render the particles which are visible after baking the FLIP part of a fluid simulation. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks in advance :)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCQaM.jpg) is a screenshot of my current viewport:

Comment: Do you want to turn the particle system into a liquid surface or render individual particles as spheres or other objects?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to render individual particles, but I already found out how. The baking of FLIP creates a particle System, so you can just change the object in the Particle System.